# Is there a way to run a Lotus Notes agent from a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a lotusscript agent that needs to run daily and requires Excel to build a spreadsheet. The scheduled agent never runs on its own as Excel is not on the server. Is there a way for me to run this agent from a batch file or is there a suggested alternative?

Comment: Did you click `Enable scheduled local agents` in your notes client preferences and schedule the agent to run locally (you have to have a local replica of the database for this to run)?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I set up enable schedule local agents with a local replica of the database, but the agent doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to insert some code in the PostOpen of the database that will launch the agent, and have your batch file open the link to the database.

To get a link to the database, you can find the database on your workspace, right click on it and go to "Application\Copy Database link" or it might be "Copy as Link", I am not sure at the moment. Then you go in Notepad and paste, you'll get a link that should look like notes://server/filepath/db.nsf.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

1 - If your aim is to buil a simple Excel spreadsheet from scratch (for reports or something else.. )  it is possible to extract the data in a txt file. Juste extract the data in an html table and name the file as *.xls 
Excel will convert the table by it own.

2 - For the scheduling : You say excel is not on the server.
Is your db on a Domino server ?

Edit : You can then schedule you agetn on the server as you don't need Excel for generating the file. 
Ritch
Regards

Comment: Yea, this db is on a Domino server and I also have a local replica.

Comment: Run the agent on the Db replicat on the server.